# Orchard CMS in windows 8.1 (when debuging) is much slower than it in Windows 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, windows-8.1

I have installed windows 8.1 a few days ago and have installed `orchard cms` on it. i noticed that it is very slow when debugging in visual studio(about 3X slower than it in windows 7). it is not obvious in smaller applications but in orchard cms which takes about 30 seconds to warm up  (in my win 7 installation) now it takes more than a minute in windows 8.1. i have no idea why this happens!? is it a SQL specific issue , an IIS Specific issue or something related to windows core performance?

i haven't compared neither `SQL` nor `IIS` performance in these two versions of windows cause i am in time constraint with this problem and i asked this question here with a hope that some one may have faced with this problem already.

any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not running the application with debugger but running the application and then attaching the debugger afterwards. If you are using IIS then use the AttachTo plugin for visual studio.

Comment: thank you so much.i haven't tried this before.just thank you.you saved me my life.i was doing it with normal debugging approach which was waste of time.now it is loading under 10 seconds.